# framer-motion layoutTransition does work in React, but not in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, layouttransition

I am trying to wrap my head around `framer-motion`, a really nice animation library which I am trying to use in combination with NextJS.
I followed a CSS tricks youtube video, which explained `layoutTransition` using this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-css-tricks-template-3-07wkh?fontsize=14&module=/src/Image.tsx&file=/src/Image.tsx:0-783

Eager to try it out I copied into my NextJs project, but I couldn't get it to work. I stripped away everything to make it even cleaner and ended up with these sandboxes: One is React, the other is NExtJS. To me they are identical, but the zooming of the image using `layoutTransition` doesn't seem to work in my NextJS sandbox, why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-zoom-forked-774up
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-haze-wii0m

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem which has taken me well to much time to fix. So the reason it doesn't work for your next app is that your framer-motion version is above 2.0. Downgrade it to the latest v1 which is 1.11.1 and you should be fine. I don't have any idea why layoutTransitions stopped working since v2, did not found any info about this problem.

I find framer-motion wonderful but it lacks good documentation and community does not to seem to be substantial yet

Comment: btw it seems that layoutTransition has been deprecated. Use layout={true} instead. I've tested it and works like a charm on the newest version.

Comment: Great! thanks, `layout` works, then I user `transition={...}` for the transition instead of `layoutTransition={...}`

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @indyanin +1 `layout={true}` works